# Variable voltage control from an ESP32

Tags: mosfet, pwm, esp32, low-voltage, variable

First, the background context:

I have a pair of [these TCS-300 landscape lighting controllers](https://www.vistapro.com/product.aspx?prodid=725) which have a cloud-only control interface, which cannot be integrated with my local home assistant.

My goal is liberate them from the cloud dependency using ESPHome or some other ESP-based device.

Each box has four zones, split into two types:

- 1 x "smart zone", intended to power other smarter devices and which is really a "dumb" output that appears to output a constant 15VAC.
- 3 x controlled-by-their-cloud zones, which appears to output 15VDC when on max power, and 8VDC when set to 50% to dim the associated lights.

I'm a little unsure about the voltages here: the smart zone only registers as 15V when I set my multimeter to AC mode, while the other zones only register when I set it to DC.

There is a switch in the panel that will set the DC outputs to be always-on 15VDC.  My plan is to feed those into something that I can control via the ESP, either through PWM, or by feeding the DAC outputs into an amplifier.

The questions I have here are:

1. Do my voltage readings make sense for typical landscape lighting? (eg: lights for trees, plants, driveway side lights, step edges)?  eg: Does it make sense that they are dimmed by varying the DC voltage?  Is the lower voltage reading something that might be visible if the output is actually being modulated via PWM?  Is there a different testing methodology I should use to increase my certainty?
2. Assuming that the voltage is actually being varied, would a MOSFET with PWM work to drive this sort of lighting, without causing harm to the lights themselves? My understanding is that the varying duty cycle of PWM would reduce power but not voltage and that that might work. What are the potential downsides?
3. If PWM output is not going to work, are there recommended options to control the higher power, higher voltage level from the esp?  I was thinking that feeding the DAC into an amplifier might work, although the esp only has 2 DACs and I have 3 zones that I want to control.  I'm hoping to find a readily available module for this.  Perhaps some kind of PWM-input from the micro controller to control the voltage level of the output?

Comment: `8VDC when set to 50%` ... the output may be controlled by PWM ... does the voltmeter read any AC value here?

Comment: There's no AC value when set to 50%. I have a pokit pro; in oscilloscope mode it shows a flat line around 8V.

I tried varying the dimmer to 25% (~8.2V), 50% (~8.5V), 75% (~9.5V) and 100% (~15V).

There is a "duty" function on the pokit, but it seems to always report ~50% for this (and when not connected!); I think because there is no obvious step or peak to read between.

So I'm a bit confused by these readings: there doesn't seem to be a linear relationship between the dimmer level and the observed voltage.

Even when set to 100us/div, there doesn't seem to be a PWM signal.

Comment: Try measuing the current that flows through the output at the different settings.

Comment: Current readings also don't make too much sense to me, as there isn't a linear relationship with the brightness level. All are DC. 100% -> 1.5A, 75% -> 2.1A, 50% -> 0.9A, 25% 0.6A